# Nikon D7000 Interval timer shooting not available for manual focus lenses

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000, samyang

I have bought a new Samyang 14mm f2.8 ED AS IF UMC lens for my Nikon D7000 dslr. I was trying to set the interval timer shooting to take a time-lapse but I couldn't see the option enabled. The date and time settings are enabled and I am using a SanDisk extreme 16gb memory card. I switched to my Nikon 70-300 lens and the interval timer shooting option got enabled. Please let me know if I am missing something or if the option doesn't get enabled for manual lenses.

Comment: Did you set your camera in manual mode?

Comment: Manual exposure? Manual focus? Both?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I havent tried with manual mode. Will try and check

Answer (score 1):

You can't be in live-view to use the interval timer.
Take out of live-view set up interval timer options.
If you need live-view to frame your shots (maybe using a tripod and have eye-piece cover on), do that then switch from live-view and turn interval timer on.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, Turn your Self Timer off.
Or Remote is another possibility, turn that off.
Try the standard Single Frame choice.
I know you mentioned the 70-300 lens, but a manual lens is not a factor on my Nikon.